# How do I do this MYSQL trigger between 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, triggers

For example If I had 2 columns on TABLE1 called "id" and "count" that contains numbers in "count" column, when those numbers reach 50 or over then I want the trigger to update a column called "reached" on TABLE2 with "yes" along with its id, in the id column

How can it be done? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're help to fix problems with something you're written, not write it for you. A good starting point would be here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 3):

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER table1_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.count >= 50
  then
     update table2 set reached = 'yes' where id = NEW.id;
  end if;
END;

|
```